# NetworkManager vs wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi

Does NetworkManager use wpa_supplicant for wifi connections ? or is it a separate program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkManager is a frontend for wpa_supplicant, so yes, it uses it to establish WiFi connections:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/master/NEWS